# hrule exceeding margin in second column

Tags: tables, margins

I'm using `tabular` to make two columns of different width. Ideally I would like to have the title of each column under which there would be a horizontal line until the end of the column, for the first, and until the margin, for the second. I used `\hrule` and it extends well past the margin.
Here is a snippet:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,array}

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=40pt,bmargin=40pt,lmargin=30pt,
rmargin=30pt}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright}p{0.4\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{L}{p{0.6\textwidth}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L R}
{\subsection*{EDUCATION}}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
&
{\subsection*{SKILLS}}
\hrule
\vspace{2mm}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

How could I achieve the desired result of the second `\hrule` not exceeding the right margin in a better way than playing with the value in the right column?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you do not put your table in a `table` environment, you should type `\noindent` in front of it, in order to leave the paragraph-indent away. I do not understand your question about the margins: You have one column with 60 % text width and one with 54 % text width. What have you been expecting to get with this? If you load the package `showframe`, you will see that your geometry settings do not look that great. Your right side margin is cut off.

Comment: Thanks I'll load that package now and take a look. I know 54% is large. What I would like is for the second  `\hrule` to stop at the right margin.

Comment: The combined width of the two columns exceeds 114% of `\textwidth`. Any chance you can shrink the column widths?

Comment: @Mico I would like to shrink the second exactly to the margin

Comment: @StephanGM Why are you using sections in this table? Do you just want to get a bigger font? This looks a bit strange. Maybe you should explain a bit more precise, what it is, you want. There are solutions for `multicol` with different widths. Have you seen those?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I used the table because it seemed like a simple way to get columns of different width. I looked here (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multiple_columns#Unbalanced_columns) briefly and it appeared like columns were of the same width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but as I mentioned in comment, your geometry settings are not optimal:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,array}
\usepackage{calc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=40pt,bmargin=40pt,lmargin=30pt,
    rmargin=30pt}
\usepackage{showframe} % shows you the cut-off side margin

\begin{document}
    \noindent % If the table stands alone, as it is, it will get a paragraph indent without this command.
    %\tabcolsep=15pt % if you want to change the blank width in the middle  
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.54\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
        {\subsection*{EDUCATION}}
        \hrule
        \vspace{2mm}
        &
        {\subsection*{SKILLS}}
        \hrule
        \vspace{2mm}
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Why is it that there is more to the right and how might I fix that?

Comment: @StephanGM I do not understand. The margins are the same as in your question. I would leave `showframe` loaded and change the geometry settings until it looks a bit more like without all the geometry settings (which is, what I would use, but the area will be quite small for a 10pt article)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution causes `Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>` with my following text and nested tables and no amount of `\relax` statements seems to fix it

Comment: @StephanGM if you have an error in your following text that is an error in code we haven't seen (adding `\relax` is unlikely to fix a missing number error)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very True, I haven't posted my entire document as I didn't think it was essential to solving the problem. I will have to look through to see what is causing it

Comment: @StephanGM try adding `\arraybackslash` as in the edited answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, but the same error still arises. I'm using `\multirow` in a couple table which I think might be causing it.

Comment: @StephanGM LaRiFaRi's answer is the correct answer for the question as asked, so probably you should accept that then if necessary ask a new question with a new example if you get errors elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree, I was planning on accepting it. I was just hoping an unanswered question would attract some more attention and possibly a solution that would work with what I already have. Thanks